# Use OpenGL types in header files without including OpenGL header

Tags: c++, opengl, types

I want to be able to use `OpenGL` types i.e. `GLenum`, `GLuint`, `GLint` etc. in my header files but I would like to avoid including `glad.h` (avoid including it in the HEADER files, but it will be included in `.cpp` files) to make sure OpenGL calls cannot be made if someone includes my file. I believe a concept like "fundamental type forward declaration" would do the trick - this is obviously not a thing.

Code example (image to allow syntax errors highlight):

[image: error]

Comment: Everything is working fine, I'm not asking for help with including/using `OpenGL`... My concern is I would like to only have to include `glad.h` in `.cpp` files, yet be able to use `OpenGL` types in my header files.

Comment: That's a terrible idea and unnecessary. All they would need to do is to ignore what you want and include the `glad.h and walla they can make calls to OpenGL. What happens if the types in OpenGL change or are not the same as what you are declaring. They either have to wait for you to do an update to your header file, update it themselves and hope that they get it right, or use something else. Smells like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: How is preventing them from being able to do so by default terrible and unnecessary? Also, as I somewhat concluded from your comment, it's not possible to do what I'm asking?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Only just saw the update.
Now, this is exactly why I created this question in the first place. I would like to have them declared EXACTLY as what they are in OpenGL- just say to the compiler: "`GLint` is unknown but it will be defined and, thus, don't throw a syntax error at me"
And that should be possible because `glad.h` eventually be included?

Comment: That's not the reason in your question. The reason you stated is to *"make sure OpenGL **calls cannot be made** if someone includes my file"*. Regardless the types can and do change based on the target platform and can change in the future. Attempting to manage them is a fruitless endeavor for the reasons I've already stated. Also C and C++ do not work in in the way you want those forward declarations defined.

Comment: I'm afraid you're missing the point that I don't want to manage these types myself but use some technique that would allow me to "forward declare" them... And I am aware that such a "forward declaration" is not possible in C++, which I stated in the question. My question is (and has been from the beginning) if there is ANY way of achieving what I stated initially. Obviously, `typedef`ing these types myself is NOT a solution and I know that...

Comment: Yes. Declare all your functions and classes as templates and require the GL related types to be passed as template parameters.

Comment: Thanks! That's one thing I didn't realise I could do and wanted to find out by asking this question. Didn't realise it would cost me -2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide typedefs for these separate from the GLAD headers. The simplest approach would be to just copy-and-paste the entire portion of the GLAD header the declares the typedefs (for all platforms) into a forward declaration header.

Comment: Is this a good idea? As discussed in the comments, if someone were to use my project, and if `glad` definitions changed, they would have to wait until I update these definitions. I know it's unlikely this would happen, but still, I'm not sure this is a good idea.

Comment: @Sheim: The typedefs in GLAD are unlikely to meaningfully change. The sizes of those types are explicitly required to be specific sizes for a particular platform. So the only thing that could cause them to change would be adding a new platform or an old platform changing its ABI. The latter is unlikely. How important the former scenario is depends on your risk tolerance.